# mysql arbitrary index query performance

Tags: mysql, database, performance

Say you have an inventory journal table with these fields:

`ID`, `ProductID`, `WarehouseID`, etc.

`ID` = PK

`ProductID` & `WarehouseID` are both FK and indexed.

Then let's say we populate 5 million rows of data into the table. I ran 2 queries.
The first query used both FKs `ProductID` and `WarehouseID`

```
SELECT inventoryjournals.id,inventoryjournals.ProductID
    FROM zenlite.inventoryjournals
    where productid = 1 && WarehouseID = 1
    limit 30 offset 2500000
```

This took 5.75s to return the result understandably because it goes through from 1st record to 2.5 mill record. But then I ran another query with arbitrary ID constraint

```
SELECT inventoryjournals.id,inventoryjournals.ProductID
    FROM zenlite.inventoryjournals
    where productid = 1 && WarehouseID = 1 && id <10000000
    limit 30 offset 2500000
```

or even this

```
SELECT inventoryjournals.id,inventoryjournals.ProductID
    FROM zenlite.inventoryjournals
    where productid = 1 && WarehouseID = 1 && id > 0
    limit 30 offset 2500000
```

This shrank the time down to 1.5 ~ 1.6s?! Does this mean it's always better to add the PK constraints in all read queries? Like id > 0 (always true)

My question is, will doing this pose any risk?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make `offset 2500000` run fast.  It *must* skip over that many rows (unless it hits the end of the table).

All 3 of your queries could benefit from

```
INDEX(production, WarehouseID, id)
```

Large offsets are a poor way to do "pagination".  It is better to "remember where you left off".  Or are you using the large `OFFSET` for some other purpose?

Comment: These 3 queries are not actual queries, they are experiments. Yes, i know offset 2.500.000 would cause it to slow down like i mentioned in the question. But you see all 3 queries has the offset of 2.500.000. However, in the first query which has no ID constraint and only used both FKs it cost 5.6 second to fetch while both 2&3 query where I arbitrarily put ID constraint with some bs logic which will return true it shrank the time down to 1.5 ~ 1.6 second. why is this? will this cause problem?

Comment: @Andrias - An FK is a constraint.  Perhaps you meant `INDEX`?

Comment: @Andrias - Did you run each query twice?  The first is to prime the cache (buffer_pool); the second is more repeatable.